# Symmetric group is not semiregular

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, self-learning, group-actions

I am learning about group actions.  This should be a fairly simple question but I want to check my understanding.

> **Claim**: Fix some integer $n > 2$, let $X=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and let $S_n$ be the Symmetric group of permutation functions on $X$. Consider the group action of $S_n$ on $X$, which will be denoted by the map $* : S_n \times X \to X$.   Then, the action of $S_n$ on $X$ is not semiregular.

Proof

Since we know $|X| \ge 3$, we can take arbitrary $x,y,z \in X$.  We know there are distinct permutations $\pi_1, \pi_2 \in S_n$ such that $\pi_1(x)= y$, $\pi_1(y)=x$ and 
$\pi_2(x)=y$, $\pi_2(y)=z$.  Thus, we have demonstrated that $\pi_1 * x = y$ and $\pi_2 * x = y$.  Thus the action is not semiregular.

The demonstration in terms of $x\in X$ is without loss of generality.

Answer (score 1):

So *semiregular* must mean no two group elements act the same way on any element of $X$.

This seems ok.

This is also called a *free* group action.